Power Supply phase margin above 90°
I am designing a 24 V to 12 V buck converter (max 3.5 A load current)  using Vishay SiC462 buck module with integrated FETs. The control mechanism is a voltage-mode constant-on-time regulator with a second voltage feedback path, Vsense, which is generated via an integrator network across the inductor to sense its current. The control scheme feels and acts a little bit like a current-mode regulator.
The datasheet describes how to derive the open loop transfer function T(s), which gives me the following gain and phase plots. At crossover (25 kHz), the phase margin is 124°, which is over 90°. Does that in fact mean, I actually have 180° - 124° = 54° phase margin?




I see a phase of about 124°@25 kHz: the phase margin is something else (exactly your 180° - 124° = 54°).
